# Alternatives to underlining an email address to signify MS Outlook "Check Names" feature

Tags: email, font, confirmation, community, addresses

MS Outlook has a feature called Check Names that converts an email address to a full name, underlines it, and makes it uneditable (aside from deleting the resolved name).

Some of my font enthusiasts are complaining that underlining breaks the font's naturally designed shape.

What is a more elegant way to implement the MSFT Outlook Check Names feature, given that I will be implementing this on a Web Page?

Comment: For the non-Windows users, could you provide an example of what this 'check names' feature looks like?

Comment: Is there any reason to not just make it a link with normal link styling for your site?

Answer (score 2):

How about a little check mark next to it that indicates it's a valid email address/user account? (See image below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A change in the background is also feasible. Plus you can use the colors to represent state, like red while is not resolved or incorrect and green when it's right.

You can blur or have the text in grey while is not right and black when it is. This may be too subtle, but is still and option.

You can combine both options, giving the idea of not really usable until is right.